# Database Version Control Tool for AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Can someone help me with a Database version control tool for AWS Dynamodb? Liquibase and Flyway cannot be used for dynamoDB. ANy help will be greatly appreciated.

At the moment we are using terraform to create and update the dynamodb table but we dont have a way of doing Database version control.

Comment: By version control, what exact features are you looking for? The only schema on the table is enforced by the service is the primary key; you also have some schema to consider for GSIs, but no enforcement on writes. Any enforcement you'd like would need to be done within your client/application layer.

Comment: thanks @ChrisAnderson-AWS for getting back. Suppose I change the hash_key or range_key in a GSI then can we keep a track of that? Just like liquibase or flyway